# How to handle compiler warning "IncludeTrailingBackslash is specific to a platform"?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

When compiling my application, there is a compiler warning:

> [DCC Warning] ... W1002 Symbol 'IncludeTrailingBackslash' is specific to a platform

How do I avoid this warning?

Comment: Implementation of IncludeTrailingBackslash calls IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter

Comment: From the [IncludeTrailingBackslash Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.IncludeTrailingBackslash): "Note: This function is included for backward compatibility only. [IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter) should be used instead."  That's been in place since Delphi 7.

Comment: @afrazier Probably since D6 when Kylix was introduced

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Delphi XE2 has another function `IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter` which can be used in place of `IncludeTrailingBackslash`. This function is supported on any platform that Delphi supports.

Comment: I don't get the reason for asking and responding to your question in just a few seconds o.O

Comment: It's Q & A style, StackOverflow offers it as a way for people to provide both a question and answer at the same time.

Comment: According to this link it's OK to answer your own questions, specially if it saves others time http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Answer (score 3):

To *avoid* the warning, turn it off in the config dialog. This turns off all other plattform specific warnings as well, which might be helpfull, as you are not going to develop Linux-Apps anyway, I assume.

To *get around* the warning, use another function (`IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter`) as you suggested.

Comment: Good pointer, but I was aiming for the idea of the *proper* solution. Of course that could raise debate, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: @alzaimar XE2 is cross-platform. It supports Win32, Mac OSX, iOS and Android.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Again, you caught me being too old to discuss up-to-date issues ;-)